# Unable to login using html5, AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

I am trying to login into a user account using a html form, with AJAX and PHP spent hours searching for solutions but could not find anything. I am new to AJAX and php so would like it if someone could help me!! It does send the request to the server (WAMP) but does not send back a response..

```
 hthml5 form

<div id="Text">

<form action="JavaScript:loginAccount()" id="loginForm">
<h1>Login into My Account</h1>
Username:<input id="username" type = "text"  value="" /><br><br>
Password:<input id="password" type = "text"  value="" /><br><br>
<div class="buttons">
<input type="submit" id="" value="Login" />
<input type="button" id="" value="Cancel" onclick="returnMain()"/>
</div>
</form>
```

```
AJAX Request to the php file

var loginAccountRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

function loginAccount() {
var url = "login.php";
var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
var passWord = document.getElementById("password").value;
loginAccountRequest.onreadystatechange = insertStock();
loginAccountRequest.open("POST", url, true);
loginAccountRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x- www-form-urlencoded");
loginAccountRequest.send("user="+userName+"&pass="+passWord);
}

AJAX response from the server

function insertStock() {
if (loginAccountRequest.readyState == 4) {
if (loginAccountRequest.status == 200) {
var response =  loginAccountRequest.responseText;
var thediv = document.getElementById("Text");
if(response==0){
thediv.innerHTML = "Sorry please try again.." 
} 
if(response==1){
stockShort();
 }
}
}
 }

php file

<?php
$uname = "";
$pword = "";
$errorMessage = "";
$num_rows = 0;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
}

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password','database');


//Grab User submitted information
$users = $_POST['user'];
$passwd = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $users AND password =   $passwd";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

if ($result) {
}
else { $errorMessage = "Error logging on";

}
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {

$errorMessage= "logged on ";

}else {
$errorMessage= "Invalid Logon";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't send back a response? So the request is timing out?

Comment: Yeah so how do i fix it please, been stuck on it for hours!!

Comment: It would be quite unusual for the request to time out before hitting PHP's execution time limit but I guess it's possible depending on your configuration. I'd add logging statements to your code and try and figure out which line is locking up the process. If I had to guess, I'd say it's either the MySQL connection or query but that really shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your JavaScript you aren't correctly assigning a callback for the AJAX call. Use:

```
loginAccountRequest.onreadystatechange = insertStock; //no parentheses
```

Second, your PHP doesn't respond with anything. Put this at the end of your PHP code:

```
echo $errorMessage;
```

Third, your callback code doesn't properly check the `response`. Instead of checking for `0` or `1`, do:

```
if (response !== "logged on ")
    thediv.innerHTML = "Sorry please try again..";
else
    stockShort();
```

Comment: After doing what you mentioned to do,  still no response?

Comment: Try removing the check for `readyState == 4` and `status == 200` and see if you get a response then. Output and log as many variables as you can as the code executes to see where it stops.

Comment: Its stops at response function insertStock()

Comment: Does it ever get called at all? Is that what you mean? If so, you need to try logging variables in your PHP and see where the problem is there.

Comment: No dont think so can you suggest another way of doing?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "if not" in my comment. Try logging the value of the PHP variables before and after your database call to see if that is causing the issue.